# Энергомост Кубань-Крым

Tags: пунктуация

Пишется без кавычек или они нужны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кавычки не нужны: **Энергомост Кубань — Крым**.  Это соединительное тире.

Пример: *В среду запустили в работу четвертую нитку энергомоста Кубань — Крым.*

[§ 8. Соединительное тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95#pp95)

1. Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими словами для обозначения пределов (‘в значении от … до’):
   *1) пространственных: Беспосадочный перелёт Москва — Хабаровск; Через эту станицу можно было выйти к большому пути Уральск — Лбищенск — Сахарная — Гурьев (Фурм.)*

Comment: Я бы пояснил так. Это не название моста, я его описание (через указание начального и конечного пунктов), поэтому кавычки не нужны.